# writing a trigger to mention reporter of a case

Tags: trigger

i have a tough time with Salesforce. How do i go about writing a trigger to specify the person who created the case as the reporter in the "reported by" field?

this is code i have written

```
trigger caseReporter on Case (after insert) {
 List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
  for (Case cas: Trigger.New) {
   if (cas.CreatedBy != null) {
  Case c = new Case();
   List<User> current_user=[SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id= :UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1] ;
    c.       id= current_user[0].id;
     cases.add(c);
     }
  }
  insert cases;
}
```

Comment: Since Reported By would be the same as Created By, why do you need this logic at all?

Comment: Also, CreatedBy is a relationship and would always be null (you meant CreatedById), there's no need for the query to get the user ID, and you can't assign a User ID to a case ID field. Also, inserting a case on a case insert trigger would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: trigger caseReporter on Case (after insert) {
      List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
       for (Case cas : Trigger.New) {

         Case c = new Case();
         c.Reporter__c = cas.CreatedById;
             cases.add(c);
 
         }

          }


@sfdcfox i tried this but it still doesn't work,

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger caseReporter on Case (after insert) { 
    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>(); 
    for (Case cas : Trigger.New) { 
        Case c = new Case(); 
        c.Reporter__c = cas.CreatedById; 
        cases.add(c); 
    } 
}
```

This code does nothing. Removing the DML at the end prevents an infinite loop, however...

Ordinarily, we want to modify the in-flight data, which we can do *before* a commit, but not *after*. So, the first change will be to change "after insert" to "before insert", then we can freely modify Trigger.new. From there, we just assign the value by copy.

The correct version of this trigger would look like this:

```
trigger caseReporter on Case (before insert) {
    for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
        record.Reporter__c = record.CreatedById;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think you might get createdbyID in beforeInsert trigger. CreatedById will be populated in a record only after insert operation.

Comment: I tried that but could not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you might get createdbyID in beforeInsert trigger. CreatedById will be populated in a record only after insert operation.

so how about trying out below snippet -

```
trigger caseReporter on Case (before insert) {
for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
    record.Reporter__c = userinfo.getuserid();
}}
```

Comment: Hi user3482434, Did it help you ?